# button id is not getting in custom action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am trying to add a custom action bar to a fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_createblog, container,false);                

        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();     
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_createblog);     
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBarBlogCreation = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_actionbarBlog);
        actionBarBlogCreation.setOnClickListener(this);

      } 
 });
```

My action bar is changed, but while i am trying to take the button id from the layout it shows null. Why it is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try next:

```
   actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_createblog);      
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBarBlogCreation = (Button) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.button_actionbarBlog);
```